# Bluetooth not working.No Adapter showing up

Tags: linux, bluetooth, pop-os

I am currently using Pop!_OS based on Ubuntu 22.04. Unfortunately, Bluetooth has not worked since installation.

It was working while using Windows 11 on the same machine however. I am relatively new to Linux.

My system info:

```
$:lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Pop
Description:    Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Output of `systemctl status`:

```
$:sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: inactive (dead)
   Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

Aug 19 08:22:00 pop-os systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being 
skipped.
Aug 19 08:24:47 pop-os systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being 
skipped.
Aug 19 08:27:16 pop-os systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being 
skipped.
```

`hciconfig -a` gives no output.

Output of `rfkill`

```
$:rfkill
ID TYPE DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
0 wlan phy0   unblocked unblocked
```

Output of `hcitool dev`

```
$:hcitool dev
Devices:
```

Output of `sudo dmesg | grep -i blue`

```
$:sudo dmesg | grep -i blue
[   73.311375] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   73.311405] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[   73.311406] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   73.311409] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   73.311411] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   73.311413] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
```

`sudo lsusb |grep Bluetooth` gives no output.

`sudo lshw | grep -i blue` gives no output.

As I see all the Bluetooth related kernel modules are already loaded

```
$:lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
btusb                  61440  0
btrtl                  24576  1 btusb
btbcm                  24576  1 btusb
btintel                40960  1 btusb
btmtk                  16384  1 btusb
tls                   114688  0
bluetooth             802816  5 btrtl,btmtk,btintel,btbcm,btusb
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth
ecc                    36864  1 ecdh_generic
xt_conntrack           16384  1
nft_chain_nat          16384  3
xt_MASQUERADE          20480  1
nf_nat                 49152  2 nft_chain_nat,xt_MASQUERADE
nf_conntrack_netlink    49152  0
nf_conntrack          176128  4 xt_conntrack,nf_nat,nf_conntrack_netlink,xt_MASQUERADE
nf_defrag_ipv6         24576  1 nf_conntrack
nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack
xfrm_user              45056  1
xfrm_algo              16384  1 xfrm_user
xt_addrtype            16384  2
nft_compat             20480  4
nf_tables             270336  57 nft_compat,nft_chain_nat
nfnetlink              20480  4 nft_compat,nf_conntrack_netlink,nf_tables
br_netfilter           32768  0
bridge                319488  1 br_netfilter
stp                    16384  1 bridge
llc                    16384  2 bridge,stp
snd_seq_dummy          16384  0
snd_hrtimer            16384  1
overlay               159744  0
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     77824  1
snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl    16384  0
snd_sof_intel_hda_common   114688  1 snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl
soundwire_intel        40960  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
soundwire_generic_allocation    16384  1 soundwire_intel
soundwire_cadence      40960  1 soundwire_intel
snd_sof_intel_hda      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_pci            24576  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp     16384  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof               200704  2 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_hda_codec_realtek   159744  1
snd_sof_utils          20480  1 snd_sof
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_hda_codec_generic   102400  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_ext_core       36864  3 
snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    69632  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl
ledtrig_audio          16384  1 snd_hda_codec_generic
snd_soc_acpi           16384  2 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
soundwire_bus          94208  3 
soundwire_intel,soundwire_generic_allocation,soundwire_cadence
snd_soc_core          360448  4 
soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_compress           24576  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      20480  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_intel          53248  1
rtw88_8723de           16384  0
snd_hda_core          114688  9 
rtw88_8723d            73728  1 rtw88_8723de
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
intel_tcc_cooling      16384  0
rtw88_pci              32768  1 rtw88_8723de
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    20480  0
nls_iso8859_1          16384  2
snd_pcm               151552  11 
uvcvideo              110592  0
intel_powerclamp       20480  0
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
rtw88_core            290816  2 rtw88_8723d,rtw88_pci
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
coretemp               24576  0
```

My kernel's `blocklist.config`

```
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac
```